# SUMIF when the range is a range of dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here's what I want to do.
I have the following table:
[image]

And another one that looks like this:
[image]

Here's what I want to do.
A `SUMIF` .. the range is the A column in the first table (picture 1) ...but the problem is here... the criteria is that I want the day in that date to be equal with the number in the 2nd table... and then I want to sum from column D.
I tried the formula but it didn't work.
Could you help me with this situation?
Thanks!

Comment: UPDATE: Thanks guys... do you know why this doesn't work?

    `SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A, DAY(Sheet1!A:A)=A2, Sheet1!D:D)`
The formula is not exactly what I used but that's the principle. Any idead if SUMIF works in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use an array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(DAY(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$11)=Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!$D$1:$D$11,0))
```

Enter the formula text with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
=SUMPRODUCT((DAY(A1:A50)=A1)*(B1:B50))

Where
A1:A50 range of dates
A1 the day to find
B1:B50 The range of values to SUM
```

[]´s

Answer (score 0):

"*the criteria is that I want the day in that date to be equal with the number in the 2nd table*"

As a date consists of a day **AND month, year**, just to provide a day as parameter isn't enough. If your intention is e.g. to get a total "per day in the current MM/YY"YYY you know what to do - create two fields for the YYYY and MM you want to look at in the table header. Basically there is nothing wrong with using dates in a SUMIF directly, like in

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$A$15,DATE(2011,9,F1),$B$1:$B$15)
```

because at the end a date is a number.

Alternatively you may use a Pivot table which aggregatees by day whatever date you have in the list, and you can sort/filter on any key field.